# how to filter association with grouped select in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, simple-form

```
Team has_many :users
User belongs_to :team
```

I can also scope my users:

```
scope :active, -> (active) {where active: active }
```

In my form, I want a select of active users grouped by teams.

```
<%= f.association :user, collection: Team.all, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :users %>
```

gives me a grouped select of users (both active and non active) by teams.

```
<%= f.association :user, collection: User.where(active: true) %>
```

gives me a select of active users.

I can't figure out the syntax to combine the two. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a method in my user.rb :

```
def self.for_select
  Team.active.map do |team|
    [team.name, team.users.active(true).map { |u| [u.name, u.id] } ]
  end
end
```

and used a grouped_option_for_select in my form :

```
<%= f.select :user_id, grouped_options_for_select(User.for_select) %>
```

This blog post was very helpful : http://andrewradev.com/2011/05/25/grouped-select-helper-methods-in-rails/

Anyone has a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

Will group all active users by `team_id`

```
scope :active_grouped, -> {where(active: true).group(:team_id)}
```

Then use this in your view

Comment: I tried in my view <%= f.association :user, collection: User.active_grouped %> but got an error PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the id to the group clause like: `group("id, otherfield")`